# resource consumption estimation of EOS transaction

Tags: cpu, resources, net

Currently, is there a tool to calculate/estimate the resource consumption(CPU, RAM, NET...) of an EOS transaction? Or any team in EOS community working on it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool as such but you can estimate the cost by looking at **how are you storing the data** (this will tell the estimation about RAM) and **how much time does your action take** (this will give you the idea about CPU).
BTW, [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuoEZBfIpN0&feature=youtu.be&t=644) video explains a lot about how to decide the cost estimation. If you get the time, go through the full video.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You can now estimate your costs for a transaction by using EOS New York's [EOS Charge](https://www.eoscharge.io/).

Methodology:

> We use a a MongoDB query that runs hourly and averages the CPU and NET resource costs experienced for every action performed on the EOS Mainnet within the previous 100,000 blocks (13.8 hours) across all Block Producers.